# Eclipse error on anonymous inner class : cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java

I am trying to create an anonymous inner class. Code is very basic but eclipse keeps complaining that 'FirstCheck cannot be resolved to a type'. Is there a basic syntactical problem here ? what am I missing ?

```
package com.javaeight.lambda;

public class LambdaCondition {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        FirstCheck fc = new FirstCheck() 
        { 
            public void runCheck(int i)
            {
                if(i > 2)
                {
                    System.out.println("It is greater.");
                }
            }
        };

    }
}
```

Comment: What is `FirstCheck`? where is it declared?

Comment: @Eran : Thanks for the hint. I had forgotten to declare the interface type. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Comment by @Eran helped fix this.